# Bash script argument with spaces

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, space

I'm trying to use Torrent-Video-Player script but it doesn't works with files that contains spaces. It's a Nautilus script.

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "peerflix "$1" --vlc"
```

"test.torrent" -> OK
"test test.torrent" -> Cannot execvp peerflix test : No such file or directory found

Comment: Why do you have nested quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
xterm -e "peerflix "$1" --vlc"
```

to

```
xterm -e "peerflix '$1' --vlc"
```

or

```
xterm -e "peerflix \"$1\" --vlc"
```

The first form is equivalent to:

```
xterm -e "peerflix " $1 " --vlc"
```

It's not what you were expecting.

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect. ``-e`` accepts multiple parameters (so that it would pass them as parameters as well). Your solution might break if you have other special characters inside (like quotes)
What you want is ``xterm -e 'peerflix' "$1" '--vlc'`` Or you can omit single quotes ``xterm -e peerflix "$1" --vlc``. However, it does not solve the problem of files with leading slashes. This should work better (in case peerflix supports it, but I don't know). ``xterm -e peerflix --vlc -- "$1"``

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, you are on a rampage, without taking the time to understand some of these questions and answers. In this case, the literal `$1` has to be passed to `peerflix`. It is not to be expanded.

Comment: @RSahu please look again. It SHOULD be expanded, because you suggested to change it to ``"peerflix '$1' --vlc"`` (which clearly expands it). So, in your answer it expands, so I kept that. Looking again at the question confirms my assumption that it should expand (because he is saying that it works without a space and doesn't with arguments containing a space).